# How to implement raven in Restify?

Tags: node.js, restify, sentry, raven

It is implemented in express look at link.

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/node/integrations/express/

but it is not implement in restify .

https://github.com/getsentry/raven-node/issues/287

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have done by this.
restify 6.0.1

```
var Raven = require("raven");
Raven.config("--yourdsnofraven--").install();

when server created add this `handleUncaughtExceptions`.

global.server = restify.createServer({
    handleUncaughtExceptions: true
});

// capture error here
server.on("uncaughtException", function (req, res, route, err)  {
    "use strict";
    console.log("i caught it!");
    Raven.captureException(err, {req: req});
    res.send(new httpErrors.InternalServerError(CONFIG.error_message.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
});
```